# Custom error format for fluent validation error

Tags: c#, fluent, fluentvalidation

I followed [Fluent documentation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Customising&referringTitle=Documentation&ANCHOR#CustomError) and I haven't found any option to overwrite default error format that is something like "'{propertyName}' must be something.". I have many validators and I won't rewrite them to .WithMessage("...").

Is there any option to change default message format?

I would like to have a similar interface to **PropertyNameResolver** that offers smart interface to change property name.

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite the messages globally by modifying the `ValidatorOptions.ResourceProviderType` as noted on the [localization page](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Localization).

You only have to define the strings that you would like to change as it will use the default string if no override is specified.